# How to Consume WCF Web Service in a Winform application from a DLL

Tags: wcf, dll, app-config

I have a requirement where I need to consume a service (ASMX or WCF) in a class then I need to consume that class in Winforms application to get the response from service.

But the problem arises as the configuration of the class (which is consuming the service) in app.config will be loaded into an app.config and this configuration file will not be read if the dll is referred in the application.

Facing the following error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyServices.IService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Comment: So what's your question? The consuming application needs to have the configuration, not the DLL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you have done. The `app.config` file in the library project could not be recognized by the Winform application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/deploying-a-wcf-library-project
There are two solutions to this issue, one is moving the configuration in the library project to the practical project (the Winform application), mainly the `system.servicemodel` section in the configuration. the other is that we hard-encoded the service configuration in the code segments, we call the service by using Channel Factory. 
Considering the below code on the client-side.

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.157.13.69:18888");
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result = service.GetData();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData();
}
```

About the `ChannelFactory`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/channel-factory
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.